# Inject functionality into two classes without common super class

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, code-duplication

I know what I wanna do sounds stupid but listen:

I have abstract classes `Entity` and `Player` (extends `Entity`) and non-abstract classes `TestPlayer` (extends `Player`) and `TestMob` (extends `Entity`).

Now I am facing the following problem:

I want to implement some abstract methods in `Entity` with the same functionality inside `TestPlayer` and `TestMob`. Theoretically I could just create another class `TestEntity` (extending `Entity`) and make `TestPlayer` and `TestMob` inherit from it. But then `TestPlayer` couldn't  inherit from `Player` anymore.

Implementing the functionality directly inside `Entity` is not an option as it isn't intended for all sub-classes to have this functionality.

What could be considered an acceptable solution other than having duplicate code?

Comment: What you want is literally an interface.. http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/102/interfaces/706/usefulness-of-interfaces#t=201608081851450672638

Comment: Of course I thought of that. The problem here is that `Player` not only adds but implements new methods.

Comment: Oh okay.. If i correctly read it this time I would  use the strategy pattern. @Androbin http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/strategy_pattern.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use the Decorator Pattern (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern). You have a interface `Entity` and two classes implementing it: `ConcreteEntity` and `Decorator`, where `ConcreteEntity` has the default logic and `Decorator` has a reference to `Entity` and delegates all method invocations. Then you can extend `Decorator`. Instead of `new TestPlayer()`, you have `new Player(new TestEntity(new ConcreteEntity)))`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's good practice but what if `TestPlayer` and `TestMob` both hold a reference to `TestEntity` instead of inheriting from it and inside every of the respective methods call the corresponding method inside `TestEntity`. #CompositionOverInheritance